# MATLAB: Brush set 'Enable' to 'off' within ActionPostCallback

Tags: matlab, callback, brush

I have a callback function (see below `function annotateSelectedRegion`) that will take brushed data and save it for later reference. I developed a GUI using GUIDE and created a class which handles a majority of the functionality and data-storage. I currently have a brush object (created in the class) which I can successfully enable in a function and set the callback to be another function within the class (see below `function startAnnotating`).

I now want the brush to automatically turn off (`set(brushHandle, 'Enable', off')`) once the data has been saved. I've seen various examples where the brush is disabled *within* the callback itself (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79531-create-a-callback-that-waits-for-the-brush-to-include-some-data-and-then-display-them).

However, when I try a similar method in my callback, I get a callback error. ***It is worth noting that when I remove the line*** `set(obj.regionSelector, 'Enable', 'off');` ***the callback function works without a hitch.*** I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong since I've seen it done in other examples. The example I referenced was done using a *programmatic* GUI. Could that have something to do with my error? GUIDE vs. Programmatic?

Brush callback

```
    % Input: 
    %        eventdata variable provides the axes being brushed...
    %        ...NOTE: The call back automatically provides...
    %        ...eventdata. You do NOT need to pass it along explicitly.
    %        
    % Output: 
    %        None 
    function annotateSelectedRegion(obj, ~, eventdata)

        currentSelection = eventdata.Axes; 

        selectedData = currentSelection.Children; 

        if isempty(selectedData) || ~any(selectedData.BrushData(:))
            % Do nothing 
            disp('please select data or load data');

        elseif ~isempty(selectedData.BrushData)           
            brushedIdx = logical(selectedData.BrushData);
            brushedXData = selectedData.XData(brushedIdx);
            brushedYData = selectedData.YData(brushedIdx);

            obj.t1 = brushedXData(1); 
            obj.t2 = brushedXData(end); 

            fillRecPairInfo(obj); 
            fillAnnotIDInfo(obj); 
            fillUniqueIDInfo(obj); 
            fillAnnotRangeInfo(obj, currentSelection);

            annotationPopUp;

        end

        set(obj.regionSelector, 'Enable', 'off'); 

    end
```

Brush is enabled in this function. The brush starts out as just an "empty" property in the class.

```
    function startAnnotating(obj)

        switch obj.annotationMode 
            case 1 
                obj.regionSelector = brush; 
                set(obj.regionSelector, 'Enable', 'on', 'ActionPostCallback', {@obj.annotateSelectedRegion})
            case 2
                % Bring up window 
            case 3 
                % Bring up window 
            case 4 
                % Bring up window 
        end 

    end
```

Comment: What is the error? I'm assuming it's something along the lines of `regionSelector` isn't a field? If `annotateSelectedRegion` is a callback then your declared inputs are not in the correct order. The first two arguments to a callback are always the handle of the invoking object and then the event data, respectively. Additional inputs are passed after those two.

Comment: @excaza No. It's a callback error (I get it whenever there is anything wrong with the callback). There's no mention of regionSelector not being a field. Could it be that I just can't modify an object's property within it's own callback? Especially when I'm disabling the object?

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to. Like I said, check your inputs to `annotateSelectedRegion` and ensure they're what you're expecting because they're probably not going to be.